# "Yourself" as a personal pronoun?

Tags: personal-pronouns, reflexive-pronouns

I was writing a message recently and I noticed that I had reflexively (probably trying to sound more official) written:

> **It should be done by either Klavs or yourself.**

instead of

> It should be done by either Klavs or you.

I searched for sources on the difference between "you" and "yourself" but I've only found explanations that "yourself" is a reflexive/intensive pronoun, while "you" is a personal pronoun. It seems to me like in my case, I was trying to use "yourself" as a personal pronoun. This should be technically wrong, but both sentences "feel" correct to me - the former just looks more official.

**Would you definitively describe such use of "yourself" as either correct or not? Is there a source to confirm it?**

Comment: In your cited context, reflexive ***yourself, myself, himself*** etc., are just "emphatic" versions of ***you, me, him***. Using them is a stylistic choice.

Comment: Reflexive pronouns are inflected forms of the personal pronouns, i.e. they are a sub-type of personal pronoun. The reflexive is optional in your example.

Comment: Certainly the emphatic use of "yourself" is in dictionaries, e.g. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yourself).

Comment: "Jill, Klavs, Peter or Ben could do it, boss."  ... "It should be done by either Klavs or _yourself_." //  "Peter and Ben say that Klavs and I aren't the right people for this job, boss." ... "Nonsense. It should be done by either Klavs or you." // Note that intensive usages ("We saw the archduke himself!" / "The people I want on this job are Ali and yourself.") are different from reflexive usages ("He washed himself in the stream.")

Comment: To use "yourself" emphatically, it's usually also required that you use the word "you" in the sentence.  So, you could say "It should be done by Klavs, or you yourself"  - the word yourself here is emphatic, not a reflexive pronoun.  I don't think it's right to use yourself as you did in the first example.  I've seen people do this because they think it sounds more official/formal, but it's not. It's a mistake. [Check this article](https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/me_myself.htm) on the subject.

Comment: @BillyKerr: Nah. As pointed out by myself and BillJ, it's entirely an optional stylistic choice in OP's *exact* cited context. But I'm sure you're right that some people choose the reflexive version *specifically* because [they think] it sounds more "official / formal". And if that's what some people *think*, I guess by definition - for them, at least - the reflexive versions *are* more "formal" (even though I doubt that things like *legal* documents are particularly likely to favour reflexive pronouns).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not sure about that. I've seen people misuse "yourself" "myself" in business letters/correspondence. This looks like a case of the same thing to me.  An example: "Send the email to James or myself" - which should in fact be "me". Check the link to the article in my previous comment - the article more or less implies such usage is incorrect.  I'm not saying it is (since I've seen people use it), but it always raises a red flag for me, like someone trying to sound official.

Comment: @BillyKerr: Maybe your preferred style guide might rule against "Send the email to James or myself", but there's no way that's a *grammatical* error. It's fine, and I personally would always use the reflexive version there *unless* I was working for a company that required me to abide by a style guide that disapproved of the usage.

Comment: [...here's one](https://wmich.edu/writing/myself) that trots out the pedantic line... *You should use "myself" and not "me" as the object, only when you are the subject of the sentence. Example: I could not dress myself.* But I don't accept that. A rule that people routinely break isn't worth calling a rule.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't have a preferred style guide, just my own style.  However I'm from the UK, so my view on it may be different. It's the kind of thing I would associate (negatively) with managers who want to appear more important/clever than they really are. This might even be a cultural/regional difference. I kind of do agree with the example link you posted, but that's only my opinion.

Comment: It can be also [an intensive pronoun, or self-intensifier](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_pronoun). And, depending on the context and the meaning you want to express, they can be both used. Ex: I, myself did it. Or, ex: [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22you%20yourself%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1999,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en&gws_rd).

Comment: Considering that this is a word choice and usage question and the answer seems to be not obvious, I don't understand why it was migrated to ELL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct. Reflexive pronouns can be used for various reasons - to sound more formal, for emphasis, or for clarity.

One of many reasons for writing 'you' reflexively is that it can also be used as a pronoun for a group of people (eg "you all") or for people in general. When assigning tasks, as your example appears to be about, saying "you should do it" could refer to a team that you belong to or be a general instruction for anyone undertaking the task, whereas saying you should do it *yourself* is more specifically putting the responsibility on you as an individual.

Comment: In the OP's example, 'yourself' is not a reflexive pronoun; it is simply an emphatic variant of 'you'. But I take your point about 'yourself' being unambiguously singular; I had not thought of that!

Comment: @TonyK Of course it's a reflexive pronoun; what else could it be?